# Java bit shifting... please explain

Tags: java

I am reviewing some code from an alarm clock project. The code uses an integer to store recurring alarm information. That is, an alarm that occurs say, every MWF. I understand that integers are simply a series of bytes, and each byte is a series of bits, so you can use that bit information to create an integer that will be unique for every pattern of days of the week. What I don't understand is the logic in these functions:

```
// is a given day "set"?
private boolean isSet(int day) {
  return (mDays & (1 << day)) > 0;
}

// set a given day to on or off
public void set(int day, boolean set) {
    if (set) {
        mDays |= (1 << day);
    } else {
        mDays &= ~(1 << day);
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain what these two function do and how they work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The isSet Function:**

Basically the expression:

```
(1 << day)
```

Means take the number 1:

```
00000001
```

And shift it over `day` number of positions to the left.  Such as if `day` were 3, you'd have:

```
00001000
```

You can use the bitwise `&` operator to check for common bits.  Such as:

```
00001000
&
00001000
```

Will equal

```
00001000
```

However,

```
00001000
&
00000001
```

Will equal 0.  Using this, you can check if that particular bit was *set*, since if you `&` the number with the bit you're looking for, you're guaranteed to get a number over 0 if that bit matches.

**The set Function:**

The expression:

```
mDays |= (1 << day);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
mDays = mDays | (1 << day);
```

This will basically force the bit expressed with `(1 << day)` to be true.  Say we wanted to flip the 1st bit on:

```
00001000 | 00000001
Equals:
00001001
```

The expression:

```
mDays &= ~(1 << day);
```

Will basically do the inverse of that.  The `~` operator inverts the bits (every 1 becomes a 0, every 0 becomes a 1).  This will ensure that the bit you're setting becomes 0, since anything `& 0` is `0`.  The existing on bits will stay, since the other bits in `~(1 << day)` are all 1.

Comment: Slightly different way to say the same thing `(binary) 00000001 << 1 == 00000010`, `(binary) 00000001 << 2 == 00000100`. It's worth mentioning that bits at the start/end are dropped when they are shifted out of the bits `(binary) 11000001 << 1 == 10000010` and `(binary) 11000001 >> 1 == 011000000`

Comment: Good point.  Bitwise operations are kinda tricky to explain.  Sometimes you just have to mess around with things under a debugger and look at the values in binary form to really understand.

Comment: What if mDays equals something like 01010101? If you take 00000001 and shift it, say 4 days, to 00010000, it still will not equal 01010101 (that is, 00010000 != 01010101), so it should return false, even though 4th bits both equal 1. What am I missing?

Comment: One other question. when shifting, does it always fill the vacant spaces with 0? Would there be a time when it might be desirable to fill the vacated spots with 1's, and is that hard to do?

Comment: @MrGibbage - You're not comparing the values, you're seeing if the and'ed value is greater than 0.  If the 4th bits are both 1, the and'ed value will have a 4th bit of 1 as well, thus be greater than 0 and return true.

Comment: @MrGibbage - Yes, shifting bits over will "fill in" the newly created empty space with zeros.  If you wanted to fill them in with 1s, you'd have to do the bit shifting first, and *then* OR the resulting value with the 1's.  I suggest reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on bitwise operations if things still aren't making sense.